# poetry: how to install from git subdirectory?

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I want to install `feast` python package with `poetry`.

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/feast-dev/feast#subdirectory=sdk/python` works okay,

but `poetry add git+https://github.com/feast-dev/feast#subdirectory=sdk/python`gives an error:

```
  CalledProcessError

  Command '['git', '--git-dir', '/tmp/pypoetry-git-feas51ct2_me/.git', '--work-tree', '/tmp/pypoetry-git-feas51ct2_me', 'checkout', 'subdirectory=sdk/python']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  at /usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:516 in run
       512│             # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
       513│             raise
       514│         retcode = process.poll()
       515│         if check and retcode:
    →  516│             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
       517│                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
       518│     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
       519│ 
       520│
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not possible in Poetry as of today as far as I know https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/755

Comment: Oy vey... And thay call it an industry standard...

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Not sure I can help you.

Comment: The feature is being developed here: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/5172

Answer (score 6):

As of [poetry 1.2](https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1.2.0/#subdirectory-support-for-git-dependencies) you can install VCS projects residing in remote subdirectories. Your `pyproject.toml` would contain the following;

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
feast = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/feast-dev/feast.git", subdirectory = "sdk/python" }
```

for example.

Comment: According to the [Poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#git-dependencies) (as of v1.7.1), the prefix `ssh://` is not needed when cloning via ssh. In fact, in my case it only works if I omit the prefix.

Comment: Confusingly, when using `poetry add`, one does need to add the `ssh://` prefix, e.g. `poetry add "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:path/to/the/project/the-repo.git`